# Replacing Ceramic Toilet Cistern

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, cistern

I have a damaged toilet cistern which is beyond repair. I was wondering if I was to install a new cistern how I would know my new one would be 'compatible' with my current set up? Is there a degree of standardisation such that I can be guaranteed I can install one I buy?

All I really know is my current one is a Twyford 2003 6L model which has a water inlet on the bottom and push button flush.

Any help much appreciated, I'm dying for a dump.

Comment: I have had better luck replacing the whole thing. On very few occasions I have been able to find one that matched up (usually in the same house or out in a barn). Then you have the new tank / bolt seals to  purchase and install.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but since it's just a crack in the ceramic can i not reuse all the bits and bobs from the old one?

Comment: the rubber seals in the bottom that connect the water tank, cistern  to the stool and the 2 bolts that connect the tank mechanically to the stool will leak if reused.
They only cost a few bucks and trying to reuse them may crack your new tank, cistern (to get them tight enough to not leak), I am sure you could goop them with RTV and give it a try but a tube of RTV cost almost as much as the new parts.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S., the tank (cistern) and bowl are sold together and are unique between manufacturers and models. You generally can't put one brand of tank on another brand bowl, just like you can't put Fiat parts on an Austin. The only likely way would be to purchase a cistern of the same manufacture which is also compatible with the model you have.

Comment: And to find out which those are, you'll have to work with the manufacturer -- so contacting them should probably be your next step if you really want to do this. Personally, I decided it made more sense to upgrade to a low-flush unit.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with keshlam, call Twyford for the cisterd's part number & get a di-rectum replacement. Butt, as long & brown as you match up the cisterd's dimensions along with all of its holes & dimensions of those holes, then you should be s@itting pretty.

If you've been delaying your latest delivery, then just use a large bucket...of water...to flush the fudge bowl, this is all the cisterd does but all fancy like. Not that I give a crap.